# Deploymets are running but didnot create pods

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-pod

I perfectly created a deployment (name is **deployer-deployment**). But no pod is running.  How I can find the problem in such a case? here is my `deployment.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: deployer-deployment
  labels:
    app: deployer
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: deployer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: deployer
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: deployer-ms
        image: bago1/deployrepo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

My deployment has created but no pods are seen
for `get deployments` and `get pods`:
[image]

And  I described the deployment here:
[image]

And I described the rs here:
[image]

Comment: Click the hiperlinks to see te results of commands

Comment: Can you check again my answer and do what i suggest at the end please

Answer (score 0):

hope you are enjoying your kubernetes Journey !

That's pretty straightforward when you know how it works:

When you create a kubernetes deployment you have to know that the deployment will create a replicaset and this replicaset will manage the pods.

So, If there is any pod created, you can ( in this order:

1 - describe the deployment

```
kubectl describe deploy <deployment-name>
```

2 - describe the replicaset

```
kubectl describe rs <rs-name>
```

( You can get the exact rs name by running: kubectl get rs )

I'm 100% sure that you will find in the describe status of one of these the reason why the pods are not created.

When the pods are finally created but not running you can then describe the pod and if everything is ok on this side you can check the pod logs with kubectl logs

However, I tried to deploy you deployment on my kind (kubernetes in docker) cluster here everything went good:

```
Every 1.0s: kubectl get po,svc,cm,sts,secret,nodes -o wide                                                                                  DESKTOP-6PBJAOK: Mon May  2 00:47:33 2022
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP           NODE                   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/deployer-deployment-6bb549df5b-2f6dm   1/1     Running   0          7m25s   10.244.3.3   so-cluster-1-worker3   <none>           <none>
pod/deployer-deployment-6bb549df5b-n4phc   1/1     Running   0          7m25s   10.244.4.2   so-cluster-1-worker2   <none>           <none>
```

and your app is working fine:

```
❯ k logs deployer-deployment-6bb549df5b-2f6dm

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.4)

2022-05-02 03:41:26.706  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.example.deployer.DeployerApplication   : Starting DeployerApplication using Java 11.0.14 on deployer-deployment-6bb549df5b-2f6dm with PID 1 (/bago1.jar started by root in /)
2022-05-02 03:41:26.710  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.example.deployer.DeployerApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-05-02 03:41:29.644  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-05-02 03:41:29.662  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-05-02 03:41:29.662  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.58]
2022-05-02 03:41:29.741  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-05-02 03:41:29.742  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2685 ms
2022-05-02 03:41:30.929  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-05-02 03:41:30.943  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.example.deployer.DeployerApplication   : Started DeployerApplication in 5.712 seconds (JVM running for 6.769)
```

I think you got an issue with you k8s cluster. according to this : [Kubernetes pod events showing as "<none>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60323290/kubernetes-pod-events-showing-as-none)  there is a good reason why your event are not showing up here, can you delete your deploy, redeploy it and again show the describe please???

Bguess

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I checked replicaset also still no useful info. I added kubectl describe rs screen on my post at end. You can check there

Comment: ok, Your describe output is very weird, i deployed your image on my kind (kubernetes in docker) cluster and everyhing went good (check my post edit)

Comment: It seems really weird. I have seen the success on your side. I deleted deployment and created again. the same issue happens.

Comment: what is the result of kubectl get events please?

Comment: One more note : Plase look at my screen shot of "kubectl get deployments" there is one more "bago-deployment" which is totally different one. On the right side you will see READY 3/3. But if you would check the screenshot "kubectl get pods"  NO any container from "bago-deployer" is occurs. THis is not related the issue of the post, but this also seems weird and may be point to find solution the real question on post. thanks.

Comment: hmm ok, lets get the output of kubectl describe deploy bago-deployment? because it says that there is 3 pod available but 0 in default namespace, maybe they are in another ns, I think the describe command will tell you this

Comment: Name:                   bago-deployment
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Sat, 12 Mar 2022 14:18:37 +0400
Labels:                 app=bago
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               app=bago
Replicas:               3 desired | 3 updated | 3 total | 3 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge

Comment: Pod Template:
  Labels:       app=bago
  Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2022-05-02T05:01:57+04:00
  Containers:
   bago-container:
    Image:        bago1/deployrepo:latest
    Port:         8080/TCP
    Host Port:    8080/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason

  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  bago-deployment-6586bbcc4c (3/3 replicas created)
NewReplicaSet:   <none>
Events:          <none>

Comment: Ok lets try an other thing: add "namespace: default" in your deployment AND pod metadata and retry please

Comment: I deleted deployment , then added namespace:default for both metadata (deployment and pod) , applied again, deployment created on default namespace. Again the same get deployments =  deployer-deployment   0/2 and No resources found in default namespace.